# Connecting to Splunk using python failing with error ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

Tags: python-3.x, splunk, splunk-api, splunk-cloud

I am trying to connect to Splunk using below python code . But failing with error ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

```
import urllib
import httplib2
username = '*********'
password = '******'
baseurl = 'https://xyz.splunkcloud.com:8089'
myhttp = httplib2.Http(disable_ssl_certificate_validation=True)
myhttp.add_credentials(username, password)
servercontent = myhttp.request(baseurl + '/services/auth/login', 'POST', headers={}, body=urllib.parse.urlencode({'username':username, 'password':password}))[1]
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "splunktest.py", line 8, in <module>
    servercontent = myhttp.request(baseurl + '/services/auth/login', 'POST', headers={}, body=urllib.parse.urlencode({'username':username, 'password':password}))[1]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1316, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1066, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1019, in _conn_request
    response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1322, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 303, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 264, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

But I am able to connect to splunk using Curl command below

```
curl -k -u ********:****** https://xyz.splunkcloud.com:8089/services/messages
```

Please let me know fix for this issue